# How can I update widget from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-widget

Solutions for update from activity not work.
This code does not work in my app:

```
Intent intentq = new Intent(getActivity(), Widget.class);
intentq.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
int ids[] = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplication()).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getActivity().getApplication(), Widget.class));
intentq.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,ids);
getActivity().sendBroadcast(intentq);
```

Comment: Please explain in detail what you want to achieve and what exactly does not work as expected.

Comment: my app is a simple students diary. i want to update widget(which display this data) when saving entered text. otherwise must waiting 30 min for automatically updating. every day of week is a fragment

Answer (score 0):

I use this method in my fragment in order to update widget by clicking updateButton. I hope this method helps you to solve your problem.

```
private void updateWidgetScreen(String updateData) {

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(parentActivity);
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(parentActivity.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(parentActivity, WidgetProvider.class);

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.remaining_money, updateData);


    Intent intent = new Intent(parentActivity, WidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, MainUtils.getWidgetID(prefs));
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(MainUtils.getWidgetID(prefs), R.id.list_view, intent);

    Intent clickIntent = new Intent(parentActivity, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent clickPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(parentActivity, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.list_view, clickPI);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);

    Log.e("updateWidgetScreen", updateData+" updateData - widgetid: "+ MainUtils.getWidgetID(prefs));
}
```